# How can I extract and store the text generated from an automatic speech recognition deep learning app

Tags: python, deep-learning, gradio

The app can be viewed in huggingface https://huggingface.co/spaces/rowel/asr

```
import gradio as gr
from transformers import pipeline


model = pipeline(task="automatic-speech-recognition",
                 model="facebook/s2t-medium-librispeech-asr")
gr.Interface.from_pipeline(model,
                           title="Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR)",
                           description="Using pipeline with Facebook S2T for ASR.",
                           examples=['data/ljspeech.wav',]
                           ).launch()
```

I don't know where the text files are stored with that very few lines of code. I would like to store the sentence text in a string.

Honestly I only know basic python programming. I would just like to store them into string variables and do something with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can open up the `Interface.from_pipeline` abstraction, and define your own [Gradio interface](https://gradio.app/docs/#interfac). You need to define your own inputs, outputs, and prediction function, thus accessing the text prediction from the model. Here is an example.

You can test is here https://huggingface.co/spaces/radames/Speech-Recognition-Example

```py
import gradio as gr
from transformers import pipeline


model = pipeline(task="automatic-speech-recognition",
                 model="facebook/s2t-medium-librispeech-asr")


def predict_speech_to_text(audio):
    prediction = model(audio)
    # text variable contains your voice-to-text string
    text = prediction['text']
    return text


gr.Interface(fn=predict_speech_to_text,
             title="Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR)",
             inputs=gr.inputs.Audio(
                 source="microphone", type="filepath", label="Input"),
             outputs=gr.outputs.Textbox(label="Output"),
             description="Using pipeline with F acebook S2T for ASR.",
             examples=['ljspeech.wav'],
             allow_flagging='never'
             ).launch()
```